# How to set email sender on mailable file or Controller with data?

Tags: php, laravel-5.7, laravel-mail

`$created array` contain email value and name and some more. `return $this->view('emails.created');` works fine , but I want to make email sender be that `$created->email`.or my controller `Mail::to('email')->from($created->email)->send(new Created($created));` like this. but two ways are not working. How can I approach, handle this variable array on my `app\Mail\Created.php` file? I need some helps.

```
class Created extends Mailable
{
use Queueable, SerializesModels;

/**
 * The created instance.
 *
 * @var created
 */
public $created;
/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($created)
{
    $this->created = $created;
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->from($created->email)->view('emails.created');
}
}
```

Comment: in `build()` method, should be `$this->created` instead of just `$created`

Comment: you can define public $email; and use as you've used $created variable. Mail::to('email')->send(new Created($created,$email));

Comment: @ViperTecPro Thank you, That Is more suitable to me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your build function with this and check. Also make sure you pass email parameter in your array.

```
public function build()
{
   return $this->from($this->created->email)->view('emails.created');
}
```

Comment: Thank you : ) Have a nice day